# Using a class type as map key_value

Tags: c++, stl

Could a variable of `Data` be used as a map key?

```
struct Data {
Data(int X, int Y) {x=X; y=Y;}
int x; int y;
}

int main()
{
   std::map<Data, int> map_;
   map_.insert(std::make_pair(Data(1,2), 0)); //error inserting
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but you either need to define `operator<` for the class type or use a custom comparison function for the `std::map`.

[There is an example of using a custom comparison function in the STL documentation.](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html)

Comment: +1 for suggesting the comparison functor, too many times it does not make sense to define `operator<`.

Comment: +1 from me as well for same reason. It might also be useful to point out that std::pair already provides this.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want an operator<, you can use boost::unordered_map.